# Docker container doesn't have any internet access

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

After working a long time on why i don't have any internet access into `Docker` i had to ask here, i read a lot of solutions which posted in this site, my problem don't resolve

what i did before asking here:

1:

```sh
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
sudo service docker restart
```

2:

```sh
OTHER_BRIDGE=br-b0b70e352d8c
service docker stop

ip link set dev $OTHER_BRIDGE down
ip link set dev docker0 down
ip link delete $OTHER_BRIDGE type bridge
ip link delete docker0 type bridge
service docker start && service docker stop

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o docker0 -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o docker0 -s 172.18.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE

service docker start
```

3: stopping `iptables` and docker daemon:

```sh
sudo service iptables stop
sudo service docker restart
```

4:forwarding rules in `iptables`:

```sh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

and then adding `DNS` into `/etc/default/docker`:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 208.67.222.222 --dns 208.67.220.220"
```

is another solution to fix this problem? i also tested internet access after rebooting system

Comment: hi, do you fix that? my container only have internet if run over host network, else cant reach external resources (ex. googleDOTcom)

Comment: @juanbits i forget